# .modal-header loses top left and right radius when new background is applied

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I am using `bootbox.js` to display some confirmation and error messages to my user.To do this I provide the `className` attribute to bootbox however I noticed that the top left and right radius of `.modal-header` dissapear when I apply a class that changes it background.Here is  a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0ynoxv3/)

I know that I can solve it by adding a `border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px` to `.errorAlert .modal-header` but I want to understand why this is happening in the first place.

In case you have problems with the link here is the minimum code to reproduce the issue:

HTML

```
<div class='btn btn-info' id = "simpleModal">
Show just a simple modal
</div>
<div class='btn btn-info' id="customClass">
Show a modal with a custom class
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.errorAlert .modal-header{
  background:red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  $("#simpleModal").on("click",function(){

    bootbox.alert({title:"Just a modal",message:"With no custom class"})
  })
  $("#customClass").on("click",function(){
    bootbox.alert({title:"Just a modal",message:"With .errorAlert class applied",className:"errorAlert"})
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because border radius in Bootstrap is applied to the `.modal-content` and by default `.modal-header` doesn't have a background. When you apply background to the modal header border radius disappears because you cover them by that red background of modal header which doesn't have border radius.

Comment: Thanks.I only want to style `.modal-header` this is why I didn't use `.modal-content`

Comment: Yeah I know, so you have to apply border radius to it, there is no other way.

Comment: Actually there is, you can add `overflow: hidden;` to `.modal-content`.